# Open or closed subspaces in weakly locally compact space.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I say that a space $S$ is **weakly locally compact** if for every $x\in S$ there is an open set with $x\in V$ with $\overline{V}$ compact.

Our teacher gave us this exercise, which is similar to previous math stack exchange exercises, except for the fact we do not ask of $\mathcal{M}$ to be Hausdorff:

> If $\mathcal{M}$ is weakly locally compact prove that if $A\subset \mathcal{M}$ is closed it must be weakly locally compact. Also prove that if $A\subset \mathcal{M}$ is open it must be weakly locally compact.

**I was only able to prove this when $A$ is closed:**

Let $x\in A$. There is an open set such that $x\in V$ and $\overline{V}$ is compact. $V\cap A$ is an open neighborhood for $x$ (in the subspace topology). Furthermore, we have that the closure of this set (in the subspace topology) is:

$$A\cap \overline{V\cap A}\subset A\cap \overline{V}\cap \overline{A}=A\cap \overline{V}\subset \overline{V}$$

Clearly, closed subsets of compact sets are compact (we can create an open cover of the larger compact set using the complement of the smaller set). Using this, we have that $A\cap \overline{V} $ is compact and consequently, $A\cap \overline{V\cap A}$ is also compact!

**This finishes the proof. It is very hard to adapt this to $A$ being open, because I cannot find a finite subcover...**

**Is there a nice counterxample when A is open?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Countable complement topology on the real numbers](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000017/) fails to be [weakly locally compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000017/properties/P000023). (Though the pi-Base uses the definition that each point has a compact neighborhood: for each $x$ there's open $U$ and compact $K$ with $x\in U\subseteq K$. Note that without $T_2$, compacts may not be closed, so $\overline{U}$ may not be a closed subset of $K$ and thus may not be compact. However, this particular space does have the property that [compacts are closed](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000017/properties/P000100) even though it's not $T_2$, so we avoid this possible technicality.)

So let $X=\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ where $X$ is the only neighborhood of $\infty$ and the subspace $\mathbb R$ has the countable complement topology. This is a $T_0$ but not $T_1$ space, it is weakly locally compact as $X=\overline{X}$ is a compact neighborhood of each point, but its open subspace $\mathbb R$ is not weakly locally compact.

Comment: If you want a $T_1$ example, let $\infty$ have arbitrary co-finite neighborhoods in $X$, not just $X$ itself.

Comment: For $T_0$: open sets are cocountable subsets of $\mathbb R$ (including all of $\mathbb R$) and $X$ overall.

Comment: For $T_1$: open sets are cocountable subsets of $\mathbb R$ (including all of $\mathbb R$) and cofinite subsets of $X$ overall.

Comment: Thanks! Let me please ask some aditional clarifications about the $T_0$ case. If $1\in V\cap \mathbb{R}$, where $V$ is open, the only possibility is that $V$ is infinite because of your topology! So $\mathbb{R}\cap V\subset F$, where $F$ is closed, we must have $F=X$. So $\mathbb{R}\cap \overline{V\cap \mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cap X=\mathbb{R}$ and I only need to prove $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact and then I will be completly satisfied. What is a clever covering of    $\mathbb{R}$ without any finite subcover?

Comment: It seems that if $\mathbb{R}\subset \cup_{i} F_i$ where $F_i$ are open sets, it is really easy to extract a finite subcover if one of these is $F_i=X$ or $F_i=\mathbb{R}$. The real  dificulty to extract a finite subcover is when $F_i=\{x_1,...x_j\}^C$. However in this case, each $x_k$ will be in a given $F_k$ (because they cover) so we can always extract a finite sub cover with at most $j+1$ points...

Comment: Let $F_i=\mathbb R\setminus\{m\in\mathbb Z: m> i\}$

Comment: Wow! Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. I am completely convinced this is a counterexample now. I am very grateful to you.